# Audio queue and EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: cocoa, core-audio, audioqueue

this is my code for generating noise using Audio Queue:

http://pastebin.com/Kn8GU72J

The problem is that my code generates an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The problem seems to be in the assignment

```
    MAAudioManager *audioMngr = (__bridge MAAudioManager *) inUserData;
```

in the callback routine.
I suspect that could be something related to the access by the thread of the class MAAudioManager.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything elsewhere in the program that retains the `MAAudioManager` instance? It looks like it's been dealloc'd by the time that the callback gets called.

Comment: You are right. The same program without ARC runs fine. It seems that ARC release the MAAudioManager instance. Ok, I need to study a bit better ARC. Meanwhile, any idea on how I can avoid that ARC releases the object? thanks!

Comment: You need to keep a pointer to the instance of MAAudioManager somewhere. You could keep it in an instance variable of the object that creates it, or the app delegate, for example.

Comment: It's also a good idea to debug with NSZombie on, you can do that in the 'Scheme' dialog, the option's called "Enable zombie objects". With that enabled you'll get more information instead of just a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Actually already have  `MAAudioManager *audio = [[MAAudioManager alloc] init];` in the app delegate. Probably I'm missing something.

Comment: That's a local variable. Once the method ends, the variable goes out of scope, and is deleted. That's why ARC is releasing your object. You need to declare `audio` as an instance variable, that means declare it in your app delegate `@interface` section (in the header file) like `MAAudioManager *audio`. A variable declared there will be around for as long as the object exists, which for the app delegate is the lifetime of the app. You can then replace the line you posted with `audio = [[MAAudioManager alloc] init]`.

Comment: You are definitely right. Thank you for your kind explanation.